# Check the gradients using finite differences

Tags: machine-learning, gradient, gradient-descent

I'm debugging my constrained stochastic gradient descent algorithm and the paper http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/192769/tricks-2012.pdf suggests to check the gradients using finite differences. I added a penalty function, but the model does not converge anymore, so i want to check my gradient as suggested in the paper.

1. Pick an example z.
2. Compute the loss Q(z, w) for the current w.
3. Compute the gradient g = ∇w Q(z, w).
4. Apply a slight perturbation w
   0 = w +δ. For instance, change a single weight
   by a small increment, or use δ = −γg with γ small enough.
5. Compute the new loss Q(z, w0
   ) and verify that Q(z, w0
   ) ≈ Q(z, w) + δg

So I can pick an example and compute the loss of this example, but my weight vector contains of ~4000 features, so i get a vector of that many partial derivatives as my gradient while the loss is an Integer, so it's not possible to compute Q(z, w) + δg. Do i have to compute the loss for a single feature of w only? Is that meant by "the current w"?

Answer (score 0):

The equation in the publication looks weird as it is not carefully described. In order to check the gradient you usually check if the difference between your "guessed" gradient `g` and
numerical gradient, which `i`th dimension equals

```
( Q(z, w + delta*e_i) - Q(z, w) ) / ( delta )
```

for small enough `delta`, and `e_i` being `i`th canonical vector (with 1 on `i`th dimension and 0 otherwise) is small enough. In other words if we denote by `g_i` the `i`th dimension of your gradient then you need to check if

```
| ( Q(z, w + delta*e_i) - Q(z, w) ) / ( delta ) - g_i | < eps

| Q(z, w + delta*e_i) - Q(z, w) - delta * g_i | < delta*eps
```

which boils down to checking

```
| Q(z, w + delta*e_i) - ( Q(z, w) + delta * g_i ) | < delta*eps
```

thus check if

```
Q(z, w + delta*e_i) ≈ ( Q(z, w) + delta * g_i )
```

which is their equation, simply **feature-wise**.